# Degrees of freedom for setting data limits with equal aspect ratio

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, aspect-ratio

I would like to exploit all possible degrees of freedom I have for defining my data limits while imposing the constraint that the aspect ratio shall be equal. In my understanding, this is the freedom to set *three* limits with it still being possible for matplotlib to fulfil my *equal aspect* constraint.

Let's say, I'd like to fix the x-limits and the lower y-limit. Then it should be possible for matplotlib to choose an upper y-limit such that my constraint is fulfilled. However, together with `set_aspect('equal')` I have a real hard time to set any data limits. matplotlib won't respect most of them.

It's essential for me to fix three limits to be able to layer different plots later. Why in the world wouldn't matplotlib let me do this?

Let's see my minimal working example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Some sample data on [0, pi]->[0, 1]
x = np.linspace(0, np.pi)
y = np.sin(x/2)**2

figure = plt.figure()
axes = figure.add_subplot()

# Set equal aspect and tell matplotlib to rather adjust data
# limits than the plotting box to meet the requirement.
axes.set_aspect('equal', 'datalim')

line = axes.plot(x, y)

plt.show()
```

1. It should be possible to set the x-limits:

```
axes.set_xlim(0, .5)
```

But that is going to look like this: [Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YV64g.png). My x-limit are not respected at all.

2. It should be possible to set the y-limits:

```
axes.set_ylim(0, .5)
```

Which looks like this: [Figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnjgE.png). My y-limits aren't respected at all.

3. Finally, I even should be able to set the x-limits and the lower y-limit:

```
axes.set_xlim(0, .5)
axes.set_ylim(0)
```

Not coming as a surprise, this also looks totally weird: [Figure 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIfum.png). At least, the lower boundary is matched correctly, but according to my experience this is more of a coincidence here. Anyway, my x-limits aren't respected at all.

Comment: _"Set equal aspect and **tell matplotlib to rather adjust data limits** than the plotting box to meet the requirement."_

Comment: Yes, but matplotlib could go well with all the constraints by just adjusting one data limit (in my example the upper y-limit).